# Pandas function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which looks as follows:
TID and FID is what I was given
[image]

I am looking for a result where :

- If FID is not empty then the result will have FID values. If FID is empty, then result will have TID values.
- if the result uses FID value, then the corresponding TID will also have FID as the result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the FID value is unique per group, use [`groupby.transform('first')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['result'] = (df.groupby('TID')['FID']
                  .transform('first')
                  .fillna(df['TID'])
                )
```

If not, you should clarify the logic, but you could probably use:

```
df['result'] = (df.groupby('TID')['FID']
                  .apply(lambda g; g.ffill().bill())
                  .fillna(df['TID'])
                )
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code should help you to get the above result.

```
# Step 1
dfTemp = df.sort_values(['TID', 'FID'], inplace=True) # Sorts the values

# Step 2
# Drops the duplicates
dfTemp = dfTemp.drop_duplicates(['TID', 'FID'], inplace=True) 

# Step 3
# In your case 1 will have ['A', np.NaN] 
dfTemp = dfTemp .groupby('TID')['FID'].apply(list).reset_index() 
dfTemp['FID'] = dfTemp['FID'].apply(lambda x:x[0]) # To get the first element of the list
dfTemp.rename(columns={'FID':'Result'}, inplace=True)

# Step 4
df = df.merge(dfTemp, on='TID', how='left)
```